# Java Double Linked List, Swap Node

Tags: java, list, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a problem by implementing a double Linked List in Java. In particulary to swap 2 following node(a node contains a political candidate in my case).
Suppose the following DLL :
head-->1 -->2 --> 3 -->4 -->tail

```
public static void reverseTwoNode(Node<Candidate> N1, Node<Candidate> N2){
     N1.setNextNode(N2.getNextNode()); 
        N2.setPreviousNode(N1.getPreviousNode());

        if (N1.getNextNode() != null)
            N1.getNextNode().setPreviousNode(N1);

        if (N2.getPreviousNode() != null)
            N2.getPreviousNode().setNextNode(N2);


        N2.setNextNode(N1); 
        N1.setPreviousNode(N2);
}
```

As output, I don't have the correct DLL from head to tail, but it's good from tail to head:

```
List of candidate 
head-->Jacques-->Joseph-->Francis-->Gilbert-->tail
Reverse
tail-->Gilbert-->Francis-->Joseph-->Jacques-->head

Reverse nodes : Francis , Joseph
List of candidate 
head-->Jacques-->Joseph-->Gilbert-->tail
Reverse
tail-->Gilbert-->Joseph-->Francis-->Jacques-->head
```

I have written several versions of this method reverseTwoNode.
I have even tried to swap datas inside nodes instead of swap nodes, I have the same problem.
It would be nice of you to help me, I spent so many hours with this simple function, I don't see what disturb...
Thank you in advance,

Maybe that result from display method ??

```
 /* Display DLL from head to tail
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 * @return str
 */
public String toString(){
    String str = "List of candidate \n";
    str += "head-->";

    Node<Candidate> iterator = this.getHead();

    while (iterator != null) {
        str += iterator.getCandidate().getName();
        str += "-->";
        iterator = iterator.getNextNode();
        }
    return str + "tail";    
}


/**
 * Return string that display DLL from tail to head
 * @return str
 */
public String reverseToString(){
    String str = "Reverse\n";
    str += "tail-->";

    Node<Candidate> iterator = this.getTail();

    while (iterator != null) {
        str += iterator.getCandidate().getName();
        str += "-->" ;
        iterator = iterator.getPreviousNode();
        }

    return (str + "head");
}
```

**SOLUTION :**
My method addNode was false, here is a correct method to add a node at the tail:

```
public void addNode(Node<Candidate> C){
    if(tail == null){
        this.head = C;
        this.tail = C;
    }
    else{
        this.tail.setNextNode(C);
        this.tail.getNextNode().setPreviousNode(this.tail);
        this.tail = this.tail.getNextNode();
        this.tail.setNextNode(null);
    }   
    this.size ++;
}
```

Comment: I think that you are not saving the first node in an auxiliar node. So you will delete it when you do N1.setNextNode. I'm not quite sure about this.

Comment: Sorry hello first of all, I didn't achieve to edit. =)
N1 and N2 follow each other N1-->N2 and N1<--N2 so I don't lose N1.getNextNode() because it's N2

Answer (score 1):

Posted code works if the following assumptions are met:

- N1 and N2 are adjacent nodes
- N1 is before N2 ( N1 --> N2 and N1 <-- N2).
- None N1 and N2 are the head or the tail element (because `reverseTwoNode` doesn't update the list)

Check it: http://ideone.com/3AKsBx

For a more general solution you need some auxiliar variables to store N1 / N2 next and previous references. Because when you do:

```
N1.setNextNode(N2.getNextNode()); 
N2.setPreviousNode(N1.getPreviousNode());
```

then at:

```
if (N1.getNextNode() != null)
    N1.getNextNode().setPreviousNode(N1);
```

`N1.getNextNode()` isn't the original value. It's `N2.getNextNode()` due to `N1.setNextNode(N2.getNextNode())`.

Here is an example: http://ideone.com/voaaTO

Answer (score 0):

Remove the if statements as they will stop you from moving head and tail nodes (may cause weird problems when one node was actually pointing to null).
I also assume that you want to swap two nodes regardless of their position (doesn't have to be two adjacent nodes).

This should simply swap the nodes and keep rest of the list intact.

```
public static void reverseTwoNode(Node<Candidate> N1, Node<Candidate> N2){
    Node<Candidate> prevNode1 = N1.getPreviousNode();
    Node<Candidate> nextNode1 = N1.getNextNode();
    Node<Candidate> prevNode2 = N2.getPreviousNode();
    Node<Candidate> nextNode2 = N2.getNextNode();

    if(N2.getPreviousNode().equals(N1)) { // test for adjacent nodes
        N2.setPreviousNode(prevNode1);
        N2.setNextNode(N1);
        N1.setNextNode(nextNode2);
        N1.setPrevNode(N2);
    } else {
        N1.setPreviousNode(prevNode2);
        N1.setNextNode(nextNode2);
        N2.setPreviousNode(prevNode1);
        N2.setNextNode(nextNode1);
    }
}
```